# Animating a toggleClass Display None/Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a list and used CSS to make is so only the first three items are shown by default. When the user clicks a Read More link it will display the remaining items.

I'm trying to animate the part where the additional list items are loaded, but can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

I've tried various CSS and JS solutions but nothing has worked. Does anyone have an ideas on how to get this to work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjEMoP

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list-list #list-more').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('#list-list').toggleClass('open');
    $('#list-more').hide();
    $('#list-less').show();
  });
  $('#list-list #list-less').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('#list-list').toggleClass('open');
    $('#list-less').hide();
    $('#list-more').show();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

#list-list ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#list-list li {
  line-height: 25px;
}

#list-list li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}

#list-list.open li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: list-item;
}

#list-more,
#list-less {
  color: #00b8e4;
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#list-more:hover,
#list-less:hover {
  color: #0084bf;
}

#list-less {
  display: none;
}

#list-more:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0 0 3px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}

#list-less:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0 0 3px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list-list">
  <ul>
    <li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi fini</li>
    <li>l sagittis nulla. Donec tempor ex augue, eget convallis est vulputat</li>
    <li>ies dui ut placerat. Quisque blandit ullamcorper sem, ut conseq</li>
    <li>volutpat ultrices nunc. Nullam mattis velit eros, non rhoncus nibh laoreet varius.</li>
    <li>ui ut placerat. Quisque blandit ullamcorper sem, ut consequat ante tristique id. Nam nisl ligula, rhoncus quis blandit vel, varius hendrerit libero. Nullam</li>
    <li>s arcu a aliquam bibendum. In id odio odio. Ut ac gravida erat.</li>
    <li>onvallis lectus fringilla non. Pellentesque velit elit, pellentesque at tincidunt pellentesque, bibendum nec sap</li>
    <li>ulus mus. Nullam nec vehicula justo. Ut vel nibh vulputate ante tincid</li>
  </ul>
  <span id="list-more">Read More</span>
  <span id="list-less">Read Less</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using keyframes? This example will fade in the text.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaYVmd

```
#list-list.open li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: list-item;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}


@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just change your javascript to this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#list-list #list-more').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('#list-list').toggleClass('open');
    $('#list-list li:nth-child(n+4)').fadeIn();
        $('#list-more').hide();
        $('#list-less').show();
    });
    $('#list-list #list-less').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('#list-list').toggleClass('open');
    $('#list-list li:nth-child(n+4)').fadeOut();
        $('#list-less').hide();
        $('#list-more').show();
    });
});
```

You don't really need the open toggle anymore in that case either. If you wanted to do it with CSS animation it would be a bit trickier because animating between display none / block doesn't really work too well in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with animation property, some simple solution would be animating opacity, see the code below:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#list-list #list-more').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('#list-list').toggleClass('open');
  $('#list-more').hide();
  $('#list-less').show();
 });
 $('#list-list #list-less').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('#list-list').toggleClass('open');
  $('#list-less').hide();
  $('#list-more').show();
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

#list-list ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#list-list li {
  line-height: 25px;
}

#list-list li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
  
}

#list-list.open li:nth-child(n+4) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  animation: displayList 500ms ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes displayList {
  0% {
    opacity :0;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  
}

#list-list.open li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: list-item;
}

#list-more,
#list-less {
  color: #00b8e4;
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#list-more:hover,
#list-less:hover {
  color: #0084bf;
}

#list-less {
  display: none;
}

#list-more:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0 0 3px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}

#list-less:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0 0 3px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list-list">
  <ul>
    <li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi fini</li>
    <li>l sagittis nulla. Donec tempor ex augue, eget convallis est vulputat</li>
    <li>ies dui ut placerat. Quisque blandit ullamcorper sem, ut conseq</li>
    <li>volutpat ultrices nunc. Nullam mattis velit eros, non rhoncus nibh laoreet varius.</li>
    <li>ui ut placerat. Quisque blandit ullamcorper sem, ut consequat ante tristique id. Nam nisl ligula, rhoncus quis blandit vel, varius hendrerit libero. Nullam</li>
    <li>s arcu a aliquam bibendum. In id odio odio. Ut ac gravida erat.</li>
    <li>onvallis lectus fringilla non. Pellentesque velit elit, pellentesque at tincidunt pellentesque, bibendum nec sap</li>
    <li>ulus mus. Nullam nec vehicula justo. Ut vel nibh vulputate ante tincid</li>
  </ul>
  <span id="list-more">Read More</span>
  <span id="list-less">Read Less</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var listHeight = $('#list-list').outerHeight(),
    fontSize = $('#list-list').css('font-size').replace('px', ''),
    lineHeight = Math.floor(parseInt(fontSize * 1.5)),
    lines = Math.floor(listHeight / lineHeight),
    closedLines = 4,
    margin = 20;

  $('#list-list').css("height", (closedLines * lineHeight) + "px");

  $('.open-list').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('#list-list').css("height", (lineHeight * lines + margin) + "px");
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $('.close-list').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.close-list').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('#list-list').css("height", (closedLines * lineHeight + margin) + "px");
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $('.open-list').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

#list-list ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#list-list {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}

#list-list li {
  line-height: 25px;
}

#list-list>button {
  color: #00b8e4;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#list-list>.open-list:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0 0 3px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}

#list-list>.close-list {
  display: none;
}

#list-list>.close-list:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0 0 3px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list-list">
  <ul>
    <li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi fini</li>
    <li>l sagittis nulla. Donec tempor ex augue, eget convallis est vulputat</li>
    <li>ies dui ut placerat. Quisque blandit ullamcorper sem, ut conseq</li>
    <li>volutpat ultrices nunc. Nullam mattis velit eros, non rhoncus nibh laoreet varius.</li>
    <li>ui ut placerat. Quisque blandit ullamcorper sem, ut consequat ante tristique id. Nam nisl ligula, rhoncus quis blandit vel, varius hendrerit libero. Nullam</li>
    <li>s arcu a aliquam bibendum. In id odio odio. Ut ac gravida erat.</li>
    <li>onvallis lectus fringilla non. Pellentesque velit elit, pellentesque at tincidunt pellentesque, bibendum nec sap</li>
    <li>ulus mus. Nullam nec vehicula justo. Ut vel nibh vulputate ante tincid</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="open-list">Read More</button>
  <button class="close-list">Read Less</button>
</div>
```